# Phonegap video capture crashes

Tags: android, video, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've made a relatively simple phonegap app, with the ability to capture images and videos and upload them to a server.

Images work fine, however when I call to capture video the camera UI appears, and when I accept the video the app crashes out with this error in logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo(who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/video/media/46536 }} to activity {myApp.test.app}: java.lang.IllegalStateException:Do not perform IO operations on the UI thread. Use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool() instead
```

I'm using phonegap 3.0.0, I've installed the correct plugins via the commandline interface, and my AndroidManifest is fine.

I'm using the demo code from the phonegap API, so the problem isn't there either.

Comment: Same problem. It was working fine until quite recently. I think something's screwy with the new phonegap update.

Comment: Good to hear, I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: Filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5052 for this issue.

Comment: Can you please paste the code that you are using or point out which example from the docs that you used? I just tried and am not able to reproduce the error anymore so I'm wondering if maybe you copied a bad example from the docs...

Comment: // capture callback
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
    var i, path, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
        // do something interesting with the file
    }
};

// capture error callback
var captureError = function(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
};

// start video capture
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:2});

Comment: Yup, that's the code that I was using too. Still unable to reproduce the error that you've been getting, on 3.1 at least. I'll try on 3.0. Are you getting any output in logcat?

Comment: MBillau - logcat output:

10-31 09:47:07.152: E/AndroidRuntime(390): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/video/media/55944 }} to activity {companyName.appName/companyName.appName.appTitle}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Do not perform IO operations on the UI thread. Use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool() instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A workaround for this issue is to edit [yourApp]\plugins\org.apache.cordova.media-capture\src\android\Capture.java

Starting at line 377, change this code

```
private JSONObject createMediaFile(Uri data) {
    File fp = webView.getResourceApi().mapUriToFile(data);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
```

to the following code

```
private JSONObject createMediaFile(Uri data) {
    // is thread checking enabled?
    boolean thC = webView.getResourceApi().isThreadCheckingEnabled();       
    // set thread checking to disabled (this works around mapUriToFile failing with IllegalStateException: Do not perform IO operations on the UI thread.
    webView.getResourceApi().setThreadCheckingEnabled(false);       
    File fp = webView.getResourceApi().mapUriToFile(data);
    // set thread checking back to whatever it was before the call above.
    webView.getResourceApi().setThreadCheckingEnabled(thC);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
```

This worked for us, hopefully it will be fixed properly soon.

Comment: No joy for me, but at least it's helped others!

Comment: Worked for me. Make sure you change the java file within org/apache/cordova/mediacapture inside the platforms directory as well as the one within your plugins directory.

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282318/phongap-capture-plugin-crashes-android

Comment: @Josh Bjelovuk What do you mean by "platforms directory" ?

Comment: The platforms directory within the root directory of your phonegap project. On the same level as www, plugins, and merges.

Comment: IMPORTANT, FOR THIS FIX TO WORK YOU NEED TO DO WHAT JOSH BJELOVUK SAYS!

user2863890, can you add that to your answer please?

Comment: I edited both and still no luck (with audio capture)

Answer (score 4):

I think a better solution would be to actually prevent using the UI thread, instead of disabling the Thread Checking.

I solved it like this:

```
private JSONObject createMediaFile(final Uri data) {
    Future<JSONObject> result = cordova.getThreadPool().submit(new Callable<JSONObject>()
    {
        @Override
        public JSONObject call() throws Exception
        {
            File fp = webView.getResourceApi().mapUriToFile(data);
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

            try {
                // File properties
                obj.put("name", fp.getName());
                obj.put("fullPath", fp.toURI().toString());
                // Because of an issue with MimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension() all .3gpp files
                // are reported as video/3gpp. I'm doing this hacky check of the URI to see if it
                // is stored in the audio or video content store.
                if (fp.getAbsoluteFile().toString().endsWith(".3gp") || fp.getAbsoluteFile().toString().endsWith(".3gpp")) {
                    if (data.toString().contains("/audio/")) {
                        obj.put("type", AUDIO_3GPP);
                    } else {
                        obj.put("type", VIDEO_3GPP);
                    }
                } else {
                    obj.put("type", FileHelper.getMimeType(Uri.fromFile(fp), cordova));
                }

                obj.put("lastModifiedDate", fp.lastModified());
                obj.put("size", fp.length());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // this will never happen
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return obj;
        }
    });


    try
    {
        return result.get();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
```

I wrapped the default method in a callable inner class. Now it gets executed in another thread.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Be sure to add the relevant imports at the top of the file:

import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;