# PhoneGap Capture Plugin Crashes Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

When I use the capture plugin it always crashes the app after taking the picture. When I click the Capture button, it opens the camera app, I take a picture, and click the check mark, then the app closes and says: "Unfortunately, HelloWorld has stopped." Then if I look in the gallery app, the photo is there. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Or is there something wrong with the plugin?

Here's what I did:

I created a brand new phonegap 3.x (3.1.0-0.15.0 to be exact) project

```
phonegap create exampleProject
cd exampleProject
```

and installed the capture plugin

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media-capture.git
```

which put org.apache.cordova.media-capture in the plugins folder. Then I built the project:

```
phonegap build android
```

This put org.apache.cordova.file in the plugins folder (because media-capture has a dependency on it), created android.json in the plugins folder. It also creates platforms/android and puts the correct js files in platforms/android/assets/www/plugins and the correct java files in platforms/android/src

I put the following in index.html:

```
<input type="button" value="Capture" onClick="capture();" />
```

Here's the entire file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="Capture" onClick="capture();" />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And add the capture(), and getErrorMessage() functions to the end of index.js:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

function capture() {
    var options = { limit: 1 };
    try {
        navigator.device.capture.captureImage(
            function(response) {
                alert("success: response=" + stringify(response));
            },
            function(CaptureError) {
                alert('Error: ' + getErrorMessage(CaptureError));
            },
            options
        );
    } catch(e) {
        alert("catch e="+e);
    }
}

function getErrorMessage(CaptureError) {
  var errorMessage = 'An unknown error occured while trying to get your media, please try again.';
  switch(CaptureError.code) {
    case CaptureError.CAPTURE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
      errorMessage = 'This app does not support the media type.';
      break;
    case CaptureError.CAPTURE_NO_MEDIA_FILES:
      errorMessage = 'No media files returned.';
      break;
    case CaptureError.CAPTURE_INTERNAL_ERR:
      errorMessage = 'The capture process experienced an internal error.';
      break;
    case CaptureError.CAPTURE_APPLICATION_BUSY:
      errorMessage = 'The application was too busy with something else to handle the media capture.';
      break;
    case CaptureError.CAPTURE_INVALID_ARGUMENT:
      errorMessage = 'Values submitted for capture were out of range, notify support.';
      break;
    case 3:
      errorMessage = 'Did you cancel? Please try again.';
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return errorMessage;
}
```

Then I build the app:

```
phonegap build android
```

and run it on my android device and experience the mentioned problem

Comment: Hey, I am experiencing the same behavior on a Nexus 7 with a fresh install. Your setup looks right, I think that this might be a bug with cordova 3.0....will post back after some more investigation.

Comment: I filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5052 to track this; there are other people on StackOverflow having this problem too.

Comment: Thanks! The answer on this question worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183174/phonegap-video-capture-crashes

Comment: Okay oddly enough, I took your example and ran it in eclipse (*gasp*) - it pointed out that your `stringify` method is undefined in your success callback. When I changed it to `JSON.stringify(response)`, everything started to work out fine. Not 100% sure this is the complete solution though since there are other StackOverflowians running into this problem...

Answer (score 1):

Use logcat (bundled with the Android SDK) to see if there are any error messages coming out of phonegap.