# Phonegap 3.1 video capture error data is null

Tags: android, video, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

Just upgraded from android 2.9 to 3.1 and now my video capture is not working. I am working on android right now.

I have the following plugins:
camera
file
filetranfer
geolocation
mediacapture
networkinformation

My manifest permissions looks like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

From what I have been testing here is what happens:

- The capture video opens the video recorder, even with the timelimit I
  have set.
- I record the video.
- It gives me the okay or close, I choose okay.
- It saves the video in my gallery (oddly as mp4 instead of 3gpp
  which I thought was how it saved videos).
- Then instead of going to the success with the mediafile it goes to
  error and tells me data is null.

Here is my code to take the video --

```
var options = {duration: 15};
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(checkLogin, mediaError, options);
```

The error message from LogCat--

```
Cordova Activity            Request code = 2
Web Console                 An error occurred: Error: data is null
```

Any ideas would be great and if you need more info please ask,
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My reputation is not high enough yet to simply add a comment, so I'll post this as an answer.  If you're still having trouble with this you may want to look at the answer to this question - [Phonegap video capture crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183174/phonegap-video-capture-crashes)

Looks like modifying the java code for Capture fixed the problem for many people.