# Why does app crash when uploading video with Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using this example [Upload Video Phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#CaptureVideoOptions) to upload videos into a server which is a php script. I use exactly this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Capture Video</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Called when capture operation is finished
//
function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
    var i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
    }
}

// Called if something bad happens.
//
function captureError(error) {
    var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
    navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
}

// A button will call this function
//
function captureVideo() {
    // Launch device video recording application,
    // allowing user to capture up to 2 video clips
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 2});
}

// Upload files to server
function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
    var ft = new FileTransfer(),
        path = mediaFile.fullPath,
        name = mediaFile.name;

    ft.upload(path,
        "http://my.domain.com/upload.php",
        function(result) {
            console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
            console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
        },
        { fileName: name });
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="captureVideo();">Capture Video</button> <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Once I stop the video and I click to "Save", the app freezes and crashes just after. What can be wrong ? I have tested it on several devices because maybe some devices can't support it but still. Even if I stop the video 1 second after or 10 seconds after, the app crashes. What is weird is that the video is in the Gallery after the app crashes.

The PHP script works well because I can send it photos and it works well so I don't think the problem comes from it.

Any advice please ?

Comment: in the capture-media plugin example the success command looks like: 'navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(
    CaptureCB captureSuccess, CaptureErrorCB captureError, [CaptureVideoOptions options]
);'

Comment: Thing is that this code is from the API documentation, it has to work... And {limit: 2} is an option if I'm not wrong

Comment: Does this example works or It's me that cannot make it work ?

Comment: Did you install GapDebug? it should give you information about the crash. And the LogCat Output should also give you information about the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just made the changes in this answer : [Phonegap video capture crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183174/phonegap-video-capture-crashes?rq=1) and the app doesn't crash anymore and I can see with wireshark that something is sent to the server even if the vid isn't well received but that's an other issue.

EDIT :

Better use this function :

```
function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
    var ft = new FileTransfer(),
        path = mediaFile.fullPath,
        name = mediaFile.name;
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.mimeType = "video/mpeg";
    options.fileName = name;
    options.chunkedMode = true;

    ft.upload(path,
        "http://192.154.23.51/upload.php",
        function(result) {
            console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
            console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
        },
        options);
}
```

I can now receive succesfully the video.

Comment: ionic.bundle.js:25642 TypeError: Cannot read property 'capture' of undefined

Comment: I'm using the latest versions of file-transfer and the file plugin. uploads work fine, but then the app crashes unexpectedly. the strange thing is, everything works fine when targeting my local dev machine (local IIS), but when I target our remote server it crashes. by that I mean, files are uploaded fine, but then when I try to navigate away or do something on the screen, the app crashes silently without an error. the project code is fine, has nothing to do with my own code. like I said the app works flawlessly when targeting my local IIS. any ideas? this is incredibly frustrating.