# PhoneGap: Upload captured video to server

Tags: html, cordova, upload, video-capture

I have created a PhoneGap app to capture video and upload it to the server. I have tried the sample code as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Capture Video</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-x.x.x.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Called when capture operation is finished
    //
    function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
        var i, len;
        for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
        }
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function captureError(error) {
        var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
        navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function captureVideo() {
        // Launch device video recording application,
        // allowing user to capture up to 2 video clips
        navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 2});
    }

    // Upload files to server
    function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
        var ft = new FileTransfer(),
            path = mediaFile.fullPath,
            name = mediaFile.name;

        ft.upload(path,
            "http://my.domain.com/upload.php",
            function(result) {
                console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
            },
            { fileName: name });
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="captureVideo();">Capture Video</button> <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

It can capture video normally, however, when calling the upload function, I got "mediaFile.fullPath is undefined" and it stopped working. Anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: does your app crash ? if it does, check my answer here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746823/why-does-app-crash-when-uploading-video-with-phonegap/29750752#29750752