# How do I upload video to server after previewed using phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

Pls I urge for assistance on how to upload video captured with phonegap android app. I could upload captured video, but I want the user of the app to watch the captured video before uploading it. That is where I'm having problem.

The code I am using is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
function init() {


document.querySelector("#takeVideo").addEventListener("touchend",   function() {
    alert("Take video");
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess,  captureError, {limit: 1, duration: 10});
}, false);

}

function captureError(e) {
console.log("capture error: "+JSON.stringify(e));
}

function captureSuccess(s) {
console.log("Success");
console.dir(s[0]);
var v = "<video controls='controls'>";
v += "<source src='" + s[0].fullPath + "' type='video/mp4'>";
v += "</video>";
document.querySelector("#videoArea").innerHTML = v;
}

function uploadFile(s) {

// Get URI of picture to upload
var img = document.getElementById('videoArea');
var mediaFile = img;
alert(mediaFile);
if (!mediaFile || (img.style.display == "none")) {

    alert("Take picture or select picture from library first.");
        return;
    }

    var ft = new FileTransfer(),
    path = mediaFile.substr(mediaFile.lastIndexOf('/')+1),
    name = mediaFile.name;
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.mimeType = "document";
    options.fileName = name;
    options.chunkedMode = true;
        options.params = params;

    ft.upload(path,
        "http://www.example.com/folder/upload.php",
        function(result) {
            alert('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
            alert(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
        },
        function(error) {
            alert('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
        },
        options);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="takeVideo">Take Video</button><br>
    <b>Status:</b> <span id="camera_status"></span><br>
    <div id="videoArea"></div>

    <button type="submit" onclick="uploadFile();">Submit</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Pls I count on your assistance to solve this challenge. I do not know how to reference "video" tagname nor extract image path from the videoArea id of the div.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29750752/3585278

Comment: Thanks @Danieboy for your response. I checked the link you quoted, it does not explain how I could upload captured video that was displayed for the view of the app user before upload. What I mean is this: capture video, display it on a container such as div, then upload the video to server from the div. Thus, how do I map the div attribute to get the video full path that I will use in the file upload function? Thanks in advance for your help.